# Issue with Magento Custom Module on Magento 2.4.5

Tags: php, module, magento2, github-third-party-apps

I am currently facing an issue with custom Magento module .

I'm trying to use the following module https://github.com/sivajik34/products-by-customer , but its not functioning.

Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Please note that Im using magento 2.4.5

Thank you

Comment: What is not working exactly? Please provide more details about errors, messages or any relevant information.

Comment: I successfully pushed the module into Magento. The module is now on Magento, but nothing happens, and nothing is shown in the configuration file related to that module. When I run 'bin/magento module:status module_name,' an error message says, 'The file does not exist. @Leonerrr_